# How to scale Windows context menu icons

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, dpi, shell-extensions

I've written a Windows context-menu shell extension in C++ with a bitmap icon attached to the menu item.  It's all working fine, except that on some machines (I think ones where the display has a custom scaling factor set) the icon displays at the wrong size:

[image]

I've done scaling code which forces the icon to its proper size on all the Windows 10 machines we've tested on, but we're still seeing problems with this on Windows 11 machines with custom scaling factors set:

```
    HDC screen = GetDC(NULL);
int hSize = GetDeviceCaps(screen, HORZSIZE);
int hRes = GetDeviceCaps(screen, HORZRES);
int scale = ((float(hRes) * 25.4 / hSize) + 64) / 128;
logger << _T("hSize: ") << hSize << _T(" hRes: ") << hRes << _T(" Scale:") << scale << ENDL;

HANDLE imageHandle = LoadImage(g_hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(resourceID),
    IMAGE_BITMAP, 16 * scale, 16 * scale, LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_LOADTRANSPARENT);
if (!imageHandle)
    logger << _T("Unable to load icon; error ") << GetLastError() << ENDL;
```

What's the proper way of handling context-menu icon scaling?  Is GetDpiForWindow() the preferred solution now?

Comment: Does the scale you calculate match the scale of Windows?

Comment: Retrieving dpi via `GetDC(NULL)` would not work correctly on systems with multiple displays with different dpi anyway. So, `GetDpiForWindow` should be the preferred solution since Windows 10.

Comment: Why don't you directly put a 256x256 icon (bitmap) and let the shell handle that automatically?

Comment: @SimonMourier -- On my Windows 10 dev machine, I've tried specifying the size as 256x256 and 0x0, with and without taking out LR_DEFAULTSIZE; all of these produce outsize icons rather than scaled ones.  (The base icon/bitmap resource is 64x64, BTW.)

Comment: What code do you use to set the icon/bitmap exactly? a 256 bitmap should work fine.

Comment: `MENUITEMINFO mii = { sizeof(mii) };`
`mii.fMask = MIIM_BITMAP | MIIM_SUBMENU | MIIM_STRING | MIIM_FTYPE | MIIM_ID | MIIM_STATE;`
`mii.wID = uID++;`
`mii.fType = MFT_STRING;`
`mii.hSubMenu = hSubmenu;`
`mii.dwTypeData = _T("&EMPSecure");`
`mii.fState = MFS_ENABLED;`
`mii.hbmpItem = static_cast<HBITMAP>(m_hMenuBmp);`
`if (!InsertMenuItem(hMenu, indexMenu, TRUE, &mii))`
`{`
`    return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());`
`}`

Comment: @SimonMourier Code above.  Does the original bmp need to be 256x256 for it to work?

Comment: Yes, I use a 256x256 bitmap

Comment: @SimonMourier I've tried using a 256x256 bitmap, and call `HANDLE imageHandle = LoadImage(g_hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(resourceID), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_DEFAULTSIZE | LR_LOADTRANSPARENT);`and it still returns an oversized icon.

Comment: Have you tried w/o LR_DEFAULTSIZE?

Comment: Same result -- it displays 256 pixels wide.